# How to publish float64 array to a topic?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am trying to publish fake joint states on a topic. My code compiles successfully, however, it gives an error "Segmentation fault, core dumped" when is run the node. Basically, I want to publish two fake positions (0) and two velocities.

```
#include<ros/ros.h>
#include<std_msgs/Float64.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/JointState.h>
float lVel = 0, rVel = 0, lPos = 0, rPos = 0;

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    ros::init(argc, argv, "custom_joint_state_publisher");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Publisher statePub = n.advertise<sensor_msgs::JointState>("measured_joint_states", 100); 
    sensor_msgs::JointState joint_values;
    ros::Rate r(10);
    while(ros::ok()){
        joint_values.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
        joint_values.position[0] = 0 ;
        joint_values.position[1] = 0;
        joint_values.velocity.push_back(0);
        joint_values.velocity.push_back(0);
        statePub.publish(joint_values);
        r.sleep();
        ros::spinOnce();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here you can see that I am using the assignment operator and pushback() function. The segmentation fault error appears with the assignment operator only. The issue with push_back function is that instead of publishing one value (0), it publishes multiple values (array of 0s) on the topic. How to publish one 0 at a time to the topic? I am using ROS melodic, Ubuntu 18.04.
Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394643/how-to-publish-float64-array-to-a-topic?/) by [faraziii](https://answers.ros.org/users/77376/faraziii/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-01-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-01-19**:
Similar questions:

- https://answers.ros.org/question/380890/unable-to-publish-float64multiarray-in-python/
- https://answers.ros.org/question/273480/publish-and-subscribe-array-of-vector-as-message/
- https://answers.ros.org/question/393396/print-uint8multiarray-values-in-python/
- https://answers.ros.org/question/372108/using-float64multiarray-with-c/

**Comment by [faraziii](https://answers.ros.org/users/77376/faraziii/) on 2022-01-19**:
Thank you for comment. I actually went through above links but couldn't fix the issue i am facing.

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-01-19**:
Please edit your question so your code is easy readable, only then we could help

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-01-20**:
Just to note: the OP is *not* publishing "a `float64` topic". This is a regular `JointState` publisher.

**Comment by [faraziii](https://answers.ros.org/users/77376/faraziii/) on 2022-01-20**:
Sorry, i didn't know how to do that but someone did that for me. Thanks to him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`resize` will solve this problem.

```
#include<ros/ros.h>
#include<std_msgs/Float64.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/JointState.h>
float lVel = 0, rVel = 0, lPos = 0, rPos = 0;

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    ros::init(argc, argv, "custom_joint_state_publisher");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Publisher statePub = n.advertise<sensor_msgs::JointState>("measured_joint_states", 100); 
    sensor_msgs::JointState joint_values;
    ros::Rate r(10);
    while(ros::ok()){
        joint_values.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
        joint_values.position.resize(2);
        joint_values.position[0] = 0 ;
        joint_values.position[1] = 0;
        joint_values.velocity.resize(0);
        joint_values.velocity.push_back(0);
        joint_values.velocity.push_back(0);
        statePub.publish(joint_values);
        r.sleep();
        ros::spinOnce();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`position` will be `resize` at 2 to make room for the assignment.

`velocity` should be `resize` by 0 to clear the assigned area. This can also be done with empty.

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2022-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [faraziii](https://answers.ros.org/users/77376/faraziii/) on 2022-01-20**:
Thank you! That's what i was missing.